# Waveguide with 3 dielectric sections

Tags: waveguide

The cross sectional dimensions of the rectangular waveguide in the figure are
\$a=50 mm, b=25 mm\$. The waveguide consists of 3 sections filled with dielectric materials such that the relative dielectric coefficient in Sections 1 and 3 is \$\epsilon_r=16\$, while in Section 2, \$\epsilon_r=17.18\$. The lengths of Sections 2 and 3 are \$l_{\alpha}=14.6mm,l_3=12mm\$. The system is fed from the direction of waveguide 1 with a \$TE_{3,0}\$ mode. Waveguide 3 is loaded by an antenna, whose reflection coefficient, measured from waveguide 3 is \$0.167e^{-j0.947}\$ at 2.5GHz. It is assumed below that \$Z_L\$, the input impedance of the antenna, is frequency independent.
I was asked to plot the loading reflection coefficients at the end of each line, i.e., \$\Gamma_{L1},\Gamma_{L2},\Gamma_{L3}\$, in the frequency band \$2.3<f<5GHz\$.

Below is my attempt at solving this, on which I'd greatly appreciate any feedback:
\$Z^{TE}=\sqrt{\mu/\epsilon}\cdot1/\sqrt{1-(f_c/f)^2}\$,
where \$f_{c3,0}=c\cdot\sqrt{(m/a)^2+(n/b)^2}/(2\sqrt{\epsilon_r})=2.25GHz\,for\,\epsilon_r=16,\,2.17GHz\,for\,\epsilon_r=17.18\$.

Therefore,

\$Z_3^{TE}=Z_1^{TE}=30\pi/\sqrt{1-(2.25/f)^2}\$, which equals approx. \$216.22ohm\, @\, 2.5GHz\$.

\$Z_2^{TE}=120\pi/(\sqrt{17.18}\cdot\sqrt{1-(2.17/f)^2})\$

The input impedance of each section would therefore be:

\$Z_{3,in}^{TE}=Z_3^{TE}\cdot (1+\Gamma_{L3}e^{-2j \beta_3 l_3})/(1-\Gamma_{L3}e^{-2j \beta_3 l_3})\$

\$Z_{2,in}^{TE}=Z_2^{TE}\cdot (1+\Gamma_{L2}e^{-2j \beta_2 l_2})/(1-\Gamma_{L2}e^{-2j \beta_2 l_2})\$

Where,

\$\beta_3=\omega \mu/Z_3^{TE}\$

\$\beta_2=\omega \mu/Z_2^{TE}\$

Hence, \$(Z_L-Z_3^{TE})/(Z_L+Z_3^{TE})=(Z_L-216.22)/(216.22+Z_L)=0.167e^{-j0.947}\$, which yielded,

\$Z_L=302.91-j1.72\$

And,

\$\Gamma_{L3}=(Z_L-Z_3^{TE})/(Z_L+Z_3^{TE})\$

\$\Gamma_{L2}=(Z_{3,in}^{TE}-Z_2^{TE})/(Z_{3,in}^{TE}+Z_2^{TE})\$

\$\Gamma_{L1}=(Z_{2,in}^{TE}-Z_1^{TE})/(Z_{2,in}^{TE}+Z_1^{TE})\$

Does that seem correct and completes the solution or am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: what's this for?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 A minor academic project.

Comment: acadamia is all about learning how to learn, so that you can get somewhere when you graduate and know almost nothing. It is no joke, but the more you learn, the more you realize how little you know.. So the C crêt is learning how to learn. The answers are already out there. You just need to learn how to find them, not by asking, but by doing.

Comment: But I did. I provided a full solution. Why couldn't I get feedback on my work?

Comment: How did you check or test your assumptions? simulation? like what is the loss tangent at such a high permittivity? and what tolerances vs f?

Comment: I didn't check or test my answers. I was hoping that maybe someone more adept in these topics could remark whether my evaluation seems correct or not and perhaps point out one or two things.

Comment: Is there anyone who could please comment on my work? I'd like to know whether I've made some serious mistakes..